# search element in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

newbie in C programming and building a linked list.

I need a function to search an element in my linked list and when I try to run the code and try and search for the word when I know it's there it tells me "word not found"

Any help with what I have?

This is my struct:

```
 struct node
  {
char data[100];
struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
 }*head, *last;
```

this is my function to search:

```
 void search(struct node *head, char words[99])
 {
while (head != NULL)
{
    if (head->data[99] == words[99])
    {
        printf("word found\n");
        return;
    }
    head = head->next;
}
printf("word not found\n");
 }
```

and this is in my main:

```
            printf("\nEnter key to search: ");
            scanf("%s", &words[99]);
            search(head, words);
```

Any help?

Comment: use strcmp instead of comparing the 100th char of each array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, scanf takes as a parameter a pointer. Instead of using

```
scanf("%s", &words[99]); //which takes a pointer to the 100th char of the array
```

use this line of code

```
scanf("%s", words); //which gives scanf a (char *), the place where the input should go. But this time it is the beginning of the array, not the 100th element
```

And next

```
head->data[99] == words[99]
```

The line above compares the 100th character of each string, not the strings. To do what you want, you need to replace that with:

```
strcmp(head->data, words) == 0
```

which takes both strings as arguments, and if it returns 0, it means both strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

First, you'll want to save a copy of the head pointer locally, so as to not change it.
In a simple list such as this, it is custom to set the next pointer of the last element to null, so your check should be for that:

```
struct node *current = head;

while (current->next != null) {
    if ((strcmp(current->data, words) == 0) {
        printf("Word found\n");
        break;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

Note also, that the incoming string should be the same size as the string in the struct (100).

Answer (score 0):

Standard strings in C are a sequence of bytes, with a special character (zero, also known as \x00 or sometimes NUL) used as the string terminator.

When you write something like

```
char words[100];
```

then you are saying that you would like there to exist an array of 100 bytes, and you would like the variable words to be the memory address of the first byte in the array.

You can read some bytes into this array with

```
scanf("%s", words);
```

As long as your input is 99 characters or less, this will work OK -- the extra 100th character is required for the null byte terminator.

Comparing strings is a bit more low-level than in other languages you might have used, like Java. You can compare strings by writing

```
if( !strcmp(head->data, words) )
```

The strcmp function tests if two null-terminated byte sequences are equal, and returns zero if they are (weird semantics, but that is C all over).

You might also want to read up on the man pages for scanf, to learn about ways to limit the number of characters written into the array (what will happen if the user enters more than 99 characters?).

If your strings can include null bytes, then C strings are a problem for you: you will need to use a different input mechanism, store a length and a value for each string, and use memcmp for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
package coderr;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class LinkedLists {


    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        LinkedList <Integer> LL = new LinkedList<>();
    
        
        LL.add(2);
        LL.add(22);
        LL.add(23);
        LL.add(52);
        LL.add(24);

        
        System.out.println(LL.contains(2));
        Iterator it = LL.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        
        System.out.print("Enter the element to search in the Linked List: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        
        IndexVal(LL,userInput);
    }
    

    public static int IndexVal (LinkedList<Integer> LL, int val) {
        
        Object[] a = LL.toArray();
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
         
        boolean check = false;
        
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            

            if (val == (Integer)a[i]) {
                
                check = true;
                System.out.println("Element Found at index: " + i);
            } 
            
            
        }
        
        if (check == false) {
            System.out.println("Element not found !!");
        }

        return -1;
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    

    
}
```

This should help. My way of approach is like, adding elements in a Linked List and converting em into an array such that we can minimise the steps.
You could remove the iterator and the while loop if inconvenient.